# How to set default value to an object in a model in c# 10

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am working a asp.netcore web api project.

I have a model named as `PaymentRequestViewModel`.In that model the object `PaymentMethodViewModel` will not come from Front end, I have to set a default value, and also I need to change the value when I need.

The model

```
public class PaymentRequestViewModel
    {
        public PaymentMethodViewModel PaymentMethod { get; set; }  // the value is null when front end sent the request
        public string TransactionType { get; set; }

        //removed rest
}
```

```
public class PaymentMethodViewModel
    {
        public CardViewModel Card { get; set; }

    }

    public class CardViewModel
    {
        public string MerchantSessionKey { get; set;} = "";
        public string CardIdentifier { get; set; } = "";
     
        public Boolean Reusable { get; set; } = false;

        public Boolean Save { get; set; } = false;
    }
```

The request from POSTMAN

```
"PaymentRequest":{
  "transactionType": "Payment", 
  "PaymentMethod" :null  // i.e Frontend will not sent the values for PaymentMethod

// removed rest
}
```

In my controller, I changes the values of those properties

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Payment([FromBody] PaymentViewModel paymentViewModel)
{
   paymentViewModel.PaymentRequest.PaymentMethod.Card.Reusable = true;  // The error occur System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 //removed rest
 }
```

Error:
`System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at TechnePaymentApi.Controllers.PublicApi.PublicOpayoPaymentController.Payment(PaymentViewModel payment`

Comment: `payment.PaymentRequest.PaymentMethod` is null. You need to create new instance and assign to it before accessing its inner properties.

Comment: Hi,I had a mistake. I have edited my question with `paymentViewModel.PaymentRequest.PaymentMethod.Card.Reusable = true;`

Comment: Seems to me your not initialiazing the "PaymentMethod" class.
`paymentViewModel.PaymentRequest.PaymentMethod = new PaymentMethod { Card = new Card { Reusable = true }};`